# Why are my background transitions not working?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create my first css-transitions, but it doesn't work. I have tried using shortcode, putting the transitions in .btn-zen-inverse:hover instead. Why isn't it working? (testing in the latest version of chrome)

```css
    .btn {
     color: white;
     font-family: 'ZLight';
     border: 2px solid white !important;
     box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba( 12, 41, 63, 0.3);
     text-shadow: none;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21) 100%);
     /* FF3.6+ */
     
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21) 100%);
     /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
     
     background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21) 100%);
     /* Opera 11.10+ */
     
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21) 100%);
     /* IE10+ */
     
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.21) 100%);
     /* W3C */
     
     filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#6bffffff', GradientType=0);
     /* IE6-9 */
     
     padding: 3px;
 }
 .btn:hover {
     transition: background-image 0.5s;
     transition: background-color 0.5s;
     -moz-transition: background-image 0.5s;
     /* Firefox 4 */
     
     -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s;
     /* Safari and Chrome */
     
     -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
     /* Safari and Chrome */
     
     -o-transition: background-image 0.5s;
     /* Opera */
     
     color: white;
 }
 .btn-zen-inverse {
     background-color: #273032;
 }
 .btn-zen-inverse:hover {
     background-image: none;
     background-color: #273032;
 }
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-zen-inverse btn-large">
    <span>Prova Zenconomy Gratis</span>
</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: You can't transition from a gradient to `none`, because it looks like that's what you're trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your transition definition needs to be a part of the base class definition

ie:

```
div {
   transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
```

instead of:

```
/* this is wrong */
div:hover {
   transition: background-color: 0.5s;
}
```

and the actual change "effect", if you will, is placed in the hover pseudo-class

like this:

```
div:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

and your base class definition:

```
div {
    background-color: white;
}
```

That being said, I'm 99.7% sure you cannot break-apart the background "short-hand" style.  Try seperating the individual styles you are attempting to transition (ie: background-color and background-image) in both the base class and the pseudo-class definitions.

EDIT: Apparently you CAN transition gradients, just not to "none".

Comment: I think it is possible to have something like `transition: background-color,background-image 0.5s,0.5s`. The different elements of transition have to be declared in the same `transition` definition, or the later will override the former. To be checked with the specs.

Comment: yes you can offer multiple styles in 1 transition declaration like this: `transition: width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;`  My point was that he was attempting to transition the `background-color` style when it was declared as part of a `background` style.  in my experience I do not think you can do that, so I was suggesting he break apart the `background` style into it's separate parts

Comment: If you mean you can't break apart a shorthand property into its components as transition properties... yes, you can.

Comment: Also, gradients *can* be transitioned to one another; they just can't be transitioned to `none`.

Comment: @BoltClock I had no idea you could transition gradients, thats awesome!  I'll have to test it.  Also...I'm pretty sure you cannot break apart the `background` property.  Specifically the `background` property, not others (like border)...I'll test this though.

Comment: @Mike Hometchko: Most likely it depends on how browsers parse the shorthand. Generally, a shorthand is expected (in the spec) to behave the same way as if all (or not all) its longhand properties were specified.